# Using for loops and either a break or continue statement to identify the number of similarities in two read strings before a dissimilarity: python

Tags: python

```
'''
Program that reads first user string input as simon pattern
then reads second user string input as user pattern.
Each character existing in the two strings is compared left to right.
For each equal character the user score is increased by 1.
The loop terminates and outputs user score upon reaching the first
character that doesn't match.
'''

user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input() #input for initial string
user_pattern  = input() #best attempt at copying simon_pattern

for i in user_pattern:
    for j in simon_pattern:
        if i == j:
            user_score += 1 #adds 1 to user_score for each equal 
                            #character in the same index for both strings
        else:
            break #if two characters do not match then end the loop
print('User score:', user_score)
```

For some reason the output is not what I would expect when I run this program though there are no syntax errors that I can find. Am I using for loops or break in a way that is producing an inaccurate result?
For example if I input: 'RRGBRYYBGY' 'RRGBBRYBGY' the output is 'User score: 6' when the fifth character in each string clearly doesn't match and the output should be 'User score: 4'.

Thanks for any help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way that doesn't use `zip()` *(requested in the comments)*:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input() #input for initial string
user_pattern  = input() #best attempt at copying simon_pattern

letters = min(len(simon_pattern),len(user_pattern))-1 # Maximum amount of letters to iterate through

for index in range(letters):

        if simon_pattern[index] == user_pattern[index]:

            user_score += 1 #adds 1 to user_score for each equal 
                            #character in the same index for both strings
        else:
            break #if two characters do not match then end the loop
print('User score:', user_score)
```

Comment: This is an excellently constructed answer. Can you please explain how the new variable 'letters' works and what exactly you (python) are doing with len(min(simon_pattern, user_pattern))-1. I understand that it sets a maximum amount of letters to iterate through, but does it join the two strings as with zip. Also, with the '-1' in the statement this program was producing incorrect outputs with larger amounts of inputs. I removed the '-1' and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your patience in helping a novice :)

Comment: `min()` returns the smallest number passed into the brackets with the least. `len()` will return the amount of characters of the array passed into the brackets. This `simon_pattern[index] == user_pattern[index]` checks if the letter from simon_pattern and user_pattern of the same index are equal, and no, it does not join the two strings.

Answer (score 3):

Your case needs to iterate through simon_pattern and user_pattern side by side, not nestedly. What you need is `zip()`:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input() #input for initial string
user_pattern  = input() #best attempt at copying simon_pattern

for i,j in zip(user_pattern,simon_pattern):
        if i == j:
            user_score += 1 #adds 1 to user_score for each equal 
                            #character in the same index for both strings
        else:
            break #if two characters do not match then end the loop
print('User score:', user_score)
```

Comment: Although I do see the logic of your code now that I have looked into the zip function, I do not think this is the way I am expected to do this because the zip function has not yet been covered in my course. I do appreciate you revealing to me a new function, but is there a way to compare two strings without the use of zip?

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer but i will explain The problem with your approach is how your nested loop works, if there are 2 strings "ABCD" and "ABDC"

You are basically taking A from first string match it with A in second string, then you take B in first string match with A in second string; so basically all comparison for characters in first string happen with first character of second string.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This makes perfect sense and deepens my understanding of for loops. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using the `break` statement just gets you out of the nested loop (j). To solve this problem, you can either use a function with a return statement:

```
def get_user_score():
    user_score = 0
    simon_pattern = input() #input for initial string
    user_pattern  = input() #best attempt at copying simon_pattern

    for i in user_pattern:
        for j in simon_pattern:
            if i == j:
                user_score += 1 #adds 1 to user_score for each equal 
                            #character in the same index for both strings
            else:
                return return user_score #if two characters do not match then end the function
    return user_score

print('User score:', get_user_score())
```

or throw an exception:

```
try:
    for i in user_pattern:
        for j in simon_pattern:
            if i == j:
                user_score += 1 #adds 1 to user_score for each equal 
                            #character in the same index for both strings
            else:
                raise RuntimeError() #if two characters do not match then end the loop
except RuntimeError:
    pass

print('User score:', user_score)
```